# Parent Transform changes each time I instantiate a new child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, instantiation

I have a Parent GameObject `ZombieArmy` with an attached script `Zombie`; its Transform changes each time a new zombie is instantiated as a child. How do I prevent the zombieArmy transform from changing and keep its transformed fixed at Vector3(0,0,0) while having the zombie have its own unique transform from each reSpawn()?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Zombie : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject zombiePrefab;
    public Transform zombieArmy;
    public Transform zombieSpawnPoint;
    private Transform[] spawnPositions;
    public bool reSpawn = false;
    private bool lastToggle = false;
    private GameObject spawn;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        spawnPositions = zombieSpawnPoint.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    }

    private void NewSpawn()   //spawn location of newZombie
    {
        if (reSpawn)
        {
            int i = Random.Range(1, spawnPositions.Length);
            transform.position = spawnPositions[i].transform.position;
            spawn = Instantiate(zombiePrefab, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation, zombieArmy);
           // zombieArmy.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }


    void Update () { //T-toggle
        if (reSpawn != lastToggle)
        {
            NewSpawn();
            reSpawn = false;
        }
        else
            lastToggle = reSpawn;
    }
}
```

Comment: From your code `Transform zombieArmy` is used only in `Instantiate()` and that is guaranteed not to change the `Transform zombieArmy`. That means `Transform zombieArmy` is changed elsewhere not in this code, and you should look up or provide other related classes to solve this issue

Comment: I also read your previous post and it seems you are having troubles with basic setups. I'd recommend you to go to look up Unity's Tutorials to learn some of the best practices in Unity. Also it will be helpful if you look up more for designing classes and their roles. Questions like "Do zombies need to know the spawner's positions?" are what should be considered before codes are written. Google SOLID principles and other famous OOP design concepts as they will help you develop great games.

Comment: This code looks fine. there must be something wrong elsewhere. find out where else accesses zombie army's transform.

Comment: Thanks guys! After realizing from your comments that it wasn't a coding error as zombieArmy was called only in this script. I put zombieArmy GameObject into another GameObject and made that GameObject the Parent, and it worked! :D

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, that Zombie script is attached to the parent gameobject, right?
Then your NewSpawn() method is a bit incorrect.. This line

```
    transform.position = spawnPositions[i].transform.position;
```

is actually changing the transform of the parent gameobject, as you say, because that's exactly what you're telling it to do.
If what you want is place each newly spawned object in the location of the randomly selected spawn point, try this instead:

```
    int i = Random.Range(0, spawnPositions.Length);    // Any reason the 0th index shouldn't be used?

    spawn = Instantiate(zombiePrefab, this.transform);
    spawn.transform.position = spawnPositions[i].transform.position;
    spawn.transform.rotation = spawnPositions[i].transform.rotation;
```